# Membership username is in uppercase?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I´m using the built in ASP.NET membership database schema to handle users and profiles. I´ve built a custom profile that inhertits from the *System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase*. In some part of the solution data are listed from the database and rendered in a html table. In code behind this list are filtered by username of the current logged in user.

Example:

```
if (usernameString.Equals(MyCustomProfile.UserName))`  
    // add to list

myRepeater.DataSource = myFilteredList;
myRepeater.DataBind();
```

This works fine in all browsers. But on some tested devices: iPad, iPhone and also sometimes in Internet Explorer 8 the list are empty. My first thought was that it was something JavaScript/HTML/CSS related that caused this. After a debugging session I´ve found that the value of the UserName property was uppercase in those cases. This value comes from the .NET ProfileBase class so there is no custom hands on.

I´ve tested the same comparing method using the built in *System.Web.Security.Membership* class. It returns the username in uppercase.

Example:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser();
if (usernameString.Equals(user.UserName))
    // add to list
```

To solve this for the moment I´ve been overriding the UserName property in ProfileBase:

```cs
public new string UserName
{
    get
    {
        return base.UserName.ToLower();
    }
}
```

The aspnet_Users standard table has two columns that holds the username: UserName and LoweredUserName. Looking into the database there are none usernames in uppercase. So how is this happen?

Comment: You should include relevant code and explain what "on iPad" etc. means. C# ASP.NET code usually does not run "on iPad" but on a server. Where do the user names come from? How do you load/store them from/to the database? Lots of uncertainty, just a few clear facts, can't reasonably answer.

Comment: Why don't you use the User's ID, say, (Guid)ProviderUserKey? This GUID won't change even if the username changes.

Comment: Yes I know. But unfortunately this is not an option in this solution. I just want to know the reason for this undesirable behavior.

Comment: The only thing that crosses my mind right now is the current culture and localization, the current thread and http context. Could this have an affect in this case?

Taken from the MSDN: "In some cases, strings can be compared differently from the full .NET Framework because of device operating system differences.". But this affects comparing? In this case it´s the UserName property value that differs from device to device so it´s there before the comparing is done.